# Project Lombok and Gradle Linting with `AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath`

Tags: java, android, gradle, lombok

I am trying to add the latest build of Project Lombok into a Gradle Project but the project linter is complaining about `AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath` for the gradle dependencies.

```
dependencies{
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'

    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
}
```

gradle build

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

The only answer I have found to be effective is to ignore all `AnnotationProcessorOnCompilePath` which is something I would like to avoid.